# How to declare assets path and include css / javascript into my views

Tags: model-view-controller, phalcon, directory-structure

I´ve just started using the Phalcon framework, I´ve read through most of the documentation described on their website but it´s still not clear to me how and where I need to include my css, and javascript files to showcase them on my view pages.

[I'm currently maintaining the follow folder structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3VBG.png)

For example my assets folder contains all my css/javascript and jquery files how would I be able to include these in my index file.

I want to know where I could declare the path to find these specific files, and how I can include these files in my view.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare it on your controller.

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // Add some local CSS resources
        $this->assets->addCss("css/style.css");
        $this->assets->addCss("css/index.css");

        // And some local JavaScript resources
        $this->assets->addJs("js/jquery.js");
        $this->assets->addJs("js/bootstrap.min.js");
    }
}
```

After this you can output your js and css link in the view:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some amazing website</title>

        <?php $this->assets->outputCss(); ?>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- ... -->

        <?php $this->assets->outputJs(); ?>
    </body>
<html>
```

Or you can use Volt syntax like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some amazing website</title>

        {{ assets.outputCss() }}
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- ... -->

        {{ assets.outputJs() }}
    </body>
<html>
```